# can i reinstall windows after deleting it?

Tags: installation, windows, data-recovery

I want to install Ubuntu in replace of Windows. 
I want to know if I can go back to Windows. If I decide this is not the right choice. 
I do not want to install Ubuntu side by side.

Comment: If you replace windows when installing ubuntu you will need to have a copy of windows on disk or somewhere so you can reinstall it if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can re-install windows by deleting the partitions created by Ubuntu during installation and have windows as your primary OS.

If your hardware permits, having both Windows / Ubuntu - side by side would be the preferred choice.

Regards
PK

Answer (score 0):

To go back to windows you will need to have an installable disk of windows, as all the windows data will be deleted when you install Ubuntu. You should also back up any documents you want to keep to an external storage device, as these will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a separate partition in order to install Ubuntu. (you can do this with gparted  (http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php).  This method will not influence your Windows installation.  At booting time you will able to make a choice with which operating system you want work.